# how to include the role to the JWT token returning?

Tags: asp.net-core, angular8, asp.net-core-3.1

What I have in my mind when navigating through the application, I want to save the token to the localhost along with role name and I will check if the users have access to a certain link. Is that how it works? with Authgard in Angular 8?. Can you give me some insight of navigating an application with the role from Identity(which is built in from ASP.net core 3.1).

**login**

```
  // POST api/auth/login
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CredentialsViewModel credentials)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);
            if (identity == null)
            {
                //return null;
                return BadRequest(Error.AddErrorToModelState("login_failure", "Invalid username or password.", ModelState));
            }

            var jwt = await Tokens.GenerateJwt(identity, _jwtFactory, credentials.UserName, _jwtOptions, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
            return new OkObjectResult(jwt);
        }
```

**Generate Token Method**

```
       public static async Task<string> GenerateJwt(ClaimsIdentity identity, IJwtFactory jwtFactory, string userName, JwtIssuerOptions jwtOptions, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings)
            {
                var response = new
                {
                    id = identity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id").Value,
                   //probably here I want to send the role too!!
                    auth_token = await jwtFactory.GenerateEncodedToken(userName, identity),
                    expires_in = (int)jwtOptions.ValidFor.TotalSeconds
                };

                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, serializerSettings);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you want to return role name with JWT token right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add claims information when generating your JWT.

Here`s an [example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/)

And another one:

[1 part(how to implement JWT)](https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-1/), [2 part(about claims here)](https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-2/)